# solaris zone migration - zoneadm attach failed on solaris 11

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, solaris-11

I'm trying to attach a solaris 10 non-global whole root zone (global zone solaris 10) to a solaris 11 global zone, but the zoneadm attach failed with below error.

```
    root@Globalzone:~#zoneadm -z nonglobalzone attach -a /ngzone1.v1.zfs.gz

    Warning: The -a and -d options to the attach subcommand may be removed in a future release of Solaris.  Use of the install subcommand is recommended.
    Progress being logged to /var/log/zones/zoneadm.20190417T205235Z.ngzone1.attach
    Installing: This may take several minutes...
    ERROR: Error: No active boot environment found.
    ERROR: Error: Command <zfs destroy ngzone1/installtmp> exited with status 1
    ERROR: Error: cannot destroy dataset ngzone1/installtmp
    ERROR: Invalid data received
                Result: Attach Failed.
```

Boot environment is available and activated.

```
    beadm list
    BE        Active Mountpoint Space  Policy Created
    --        ------ ---------- -----  ------ -------
    solaris-2 NR     /          66.72G static 2013-11-07 06:27
```

Here is the Source/destination info.

Source:
Global zone - solaris 10
nonglobal zone - solaris 10

Destination
Global zone - solaris 11.

```
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:52:35 PM PDT] Pinning nonglobalzone
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:52:35 PM PDT] ZFS send stream
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:52:35 PM PDT]     Installing: This may take several minutes...
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:52:36 PM PDT] gzcat / nonglobalzone.v1.zfs.gz | zfs receive -F -u -x zoned nonglobalzone/installtmp/ds
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:55:06 PM PDT] ERROR: Error: No active boot environment found.
    cannot destroy 'nonglobalzone/installtmp': filesystem has children
    use '-r' to destroy the following datasets:
    nonglobalzone/installtmp/ds@v2v
    nonglobalzone/installtmp/ds@v2v1
    nonglobalzone/installtmp/ds
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:55:06 PM PDT] ERROR: Error: Command <zfs destroy nonglobalzone/installtmp> exited with status 1
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:55:06 PM PDT] ERROR: Error: cannot destroy dataset nonglobalzone/installtmp
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:55:06 PM PDT] ERROR: Invalid data received
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:55:06 PM PDT] Destroying datasets under nonglobalzone that are not pinned
    [Wednesday, April 17, 2019 01:55:06 PM PDT] Destroyed unpinned snapshot nonglobalzone/installtmp/ds@v2v
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This command is not correct:

```
zoneadm -z attach -a /ngzone1.v1.zfs.gz
```

Per [the `zoneadm` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54764/zoneadm-1m.html):

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> zoneadm -z zonename [-u uuid-match] subcommand 
>     [subcommand_options]
> ```
>
> ...

Note the "zoneadm -z **zonename** ... subcommand ..." format.

You omitted the `zonename` parameter from the command you posted.

The command, per [the **Migrating an Existing Zone on an Oracle Solaris 10 System** page of the Solaris 11 Administration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1460/gjroc.html) is:

> ```
> zoneadm -z my-zone attach -a /zones/my-zone.cpio.gz
> ```

Again - note the `zonename` parameter, which is `my-zone` in that example.

Comment: Never mind.  I was executing the same command.  I had to remove the servername for security reasons while mentioning here.

zoneadm -z <nonglobal> attach -a /zones/my-zone.cpio.gz

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I have also updated the detailed error.  Not sure, where I went wrong.